# Ultrasonic program giving me an odd error

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I created a program that is intended to turn a servo motor 180 degrees then back if an object is within 20cm of the ultrasonic sensor. This works fine except sometimes when the if condition is not met. In this case, the motor doesn't move at all and the distance is put into the serial monitor. This works fine sometimes, but in most cases the serial monitor just prints 0 repeatedly and I have to restart the program for it to work again. Even when I put an object within 20cm of the sensor it still prints 0. I am quite new to Arduino so this really just stumped me haha. Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo1;  // create servo object to control a servo

#define trigPin 13
#define echoPin 12


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  servo1.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}


void loop()
{
  long duration = 0, distance = 0;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;

  if(distance > 2 && distance < 20){
    servo1.write(180);
    Serial.println(distance);
    delay(1000);
    servo1.write(-180);
  }
else{
  servo1.write(0);
  Serial.println(distance);
}

 delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: did you check wire connection?

Answer (score 0):

See what happens when you try this code, as I cleaned it up a little bit:

```
#include <Servo.h>

#define trigPin 13
#define echoPin 12

Servo servo1;  // create servo object to control a servo

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  servo1.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  float duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration / 2) * 29.1;

  if (duration) {
    if (distance > 2 && distance < 20) {
      servo1.write(180);
      Serial.println(distance);
      delay(1000);
      servo1.write(-180);
    }

    else {
      servo1.write(0);
      Serial.println(distance);
    }
  }
  delay(2000);
}
```

I think if you use a float it might work. However, if it doesn't work, try switching up the pin assignments to different pins on the Arduino and see if that works. If the distance measurment is off the best way to adjust it is with the multiplied value in the distance variable in the `void loop ()`.This one works for me.

Comment: This code did help a bit, but overall I think I've decided that my Ultrasonic sensor is slightly faulty. I believe this because I tried 3 different libraries just to ensure that my sensor was accurate and with each one I kept getting random streaks of 0s and sometimes completely random numbers that were nowhere near where my object was at. I also changed my connections and made sure each was making proper contact.

Comment: @N.Cut What kind of sensor is it?

Comment: It is an HC-SR04 Sensor, I've had it for a while so I'm assuming it has gotten damaged over time possibly, or it just came faulty from the factory.